# how to process a php code (in ajax) without returning any value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session

I hope these lines would explain the question:

```
//in javascript
function foo(sessionName){
    var u = "test.php?q="+sessionName+"&r="+parseInt(Math.random()*9999999);
    xmlHttpObj.open("get", u, true);
    xmlHttpObj.send();
}       

//in php

$q = $_GET['q'];
unset($_SESSION[$q]);
```

Like you see, I don't want any value returned, I just want to unset the specific session.

Comment: So what's the problem? Just don't handle the return

Comment: This doesn't make any sense...I don't even know how to suggest an improvement.

Comment: you can't, ajax will erase the original value if you don't return any value, it's like returning `echo"";`

Comment: Sorry, *"ajax will erase the original value"* doesn't make sense. What's the concrete problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ever have to return a value, if you access and run the script it will do it's job. The problem will be that you will have no way of *knowing* if it succeeded, so it's best to return a success/failure value in general. However, since `unset()` doesn't actually return a value there is no need in this case.

Comment: This is assuming typos rather than actual errors in your example :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works. I suppose your problem is a typo in the variable name?

```
var u = "test.php?q="+sessionName+"&r="+parseInt(Math.random()*9999999);
                  ^
$n = $_GET['n'];
            ^
```

Comment: just ignore if there's a typo, how to return nothing?

Comment: @Bagong Just... don't return anything. Looks like you're already doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to still return a value indicating wether it worked or not. Even though this code should work just fine.

Adding this to the end of your script will give you an indicator wether it worked or not.

```
if (isset($_SESSION[$n])) {
    echo 'success';
}
else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```